# Thread or timer to read sensor data out?

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, synchronization

My Linux C++ application is periodically reading sensor data. Readout is done by simple file I/O operation (OS is writing to file, application is reading from this file).
Some information about my platform:

- I have single core processor with hyper-threading
- sensor data update frequency is 1 second
- application GUI runs in main thread and shouldn't be blocked

I considered two approaches for sensor data read out:

- timer running in main application thread
- separate thread with infinite loop which does sensor data readout and then sleeps

Which approach makes more sens, are there any other alternatives ? What are the costs of both solution (e.g. blocking of main thread in first or context switching in second approach) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What else does the main thread have to do? Is it ok if it blocks? If so, then you dont need to do the timer, etc in a separate thread.

If the main thread cant block waiting for the periodic timer, then a separate thread must be created. The communication of data between the threads can be via an object that is accessible to both threads and protected via a mutex (look up pthread_mutex_t), which is quite simple to do.

As for which solution would be better and what are the costs, it depends on what else the main  thread is doing. But for something this simple, either way should be about the same, and the context switching shouldnt affect anything. What should affect performance the most is how performance intensive the reads are.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about your application or the hardware, but here are a few things to consider:

- If you use a thread, you will have to create a communication channel of some sort to tell the main thread that data has been updated. Usually this would be a pipe(), as signals are inherently unreliable and condition locks don't work with I/O multiplexing (i.e. select()/poll()).
- Can you get the entire set of data without blocking? If so, then just reading it in the main thread is probably easier. However, if your read can block you'll probably need some more "keep track of my read state to incorporate it into my central select()", whereas a thread can just block until more data is available.

Thus, neither solution is automatically "easier" to do.

I wouldn't worry about "context switching" for a read that only occurs once per second; that's irrelevant.

Comment: Why would you need a communication channel for a thread? Why not just use a shared object protected by a mutex? A pipe is overkill for threads, perhaps you're thinking of a forked or separate process???

Answer (score 1):

I believe that cost of the context switch once a second is not an issue even for single-core CPU without hyper-threading especially taking to the account that the application is running in user space, thus is not really time-critical. The polling of your sensor in the main thread complicates the logic of the application. So, I would recommend you to start a thread for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A sleep-loop will skew the timing because each iteration is going to take longer than 1sec. Timers don't have that problem, and they are made for this scenario. So choose a timer.

Performance-wise there is no difference because you are only triggering once a second.

Comment: Its true that the time will be skewed unless you recalculate the time to sleep each time. How do you use a timer in C++? Ive seen an alarm that sends signals, but that should probably not be used in this scenario.

Comment: Skew is only part of my point. What you need semantically is a timer. So use a timer. It is the natural solution. *How* to use a timer is a different question though (that surely has been answered already!).

Answer (score 0):

If the Linux driver is reading a sensor data and writing it to a device file every second, you shouldn't duplicate the timer logic in your application. It may happen that after 1 second sleep your application will still read the same data as 1 second ago. A better approach would be to have a thread that would call a blocking read on a device file. When new sensor data is available, blocking read returns, the thread can process the data and call read again.

Comment: My goal is to avoid blocking my main (GUI) thread. What do you mean by "call blocking read on a device file" ?

Comment: @tommyk: I imagine Linux exposes a device file to which sensor events are written such as /dev/sensor. This is standard approach, is it used in your case? If it is the case, if you open this file and call read() on it, the read will block until Linux outputs a sensor event. If Linux generates such event every 1s, the read will block for 1s and you don't need any sleep() or timer in your application. You should call read from a separate thread, not a GUI thread.